How can I make the form element inherit it's parent's styling?
I have the problem of retrospectively adding a <form /> element to wrap my form inputs.
Adding a new html element disrupts the layout, so I end up having to duplicate the parent's css styling onto the <form />.
Is there a way to inherit layout styling from a parent element?
Here is an example, I've added the <form /> element, and it's thrown out the layout. I'd like the inputs to flow vertically with a gap, without having to manually duplicate/reapply the parent css styling.
For example:


.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
form {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
<div class="parent">
  <form>
    <input class="child" placeholder="a" />
    <input class="child" placeholder="b" />
  </form>
</div>




Not without manually doing a bunch of display: inherit etc. Just change the CSS selector. .parent, .parent form {...}

I just found out I can inherit css attributes!
Inherit specific CSS Attributes
e.g.
form {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inherit;
  flex-direction: inherit;
  gap: inherit;
}

Inherit all CSS Attributes
You can still apply overrides - for example removing the padding.
form {
  all: inherit;
  padding: 0;
}

Example:


.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
form {
  all: inherit;
  padding: 0;
}
.child {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
<div class="parent">
  <form>
    <input class="child" placeholder="a" />
    <input class="child" placeholder="b" />
  </form>
</div>




You could also simply do .parent, form { the CSS }

Thanks @TemaniAfif - that would make a great answer
